# How i can make welcome command and add option to set channel where it'll be sending?

Tags: bots, discord.js

I'm new discord bot developer and I wanted to add command that allows to set welcome channel in my bot, but I don't really know how to do it. I tried to find an answer, but all of them have defined id already, so it won't work on other servers. If you can help me or give me tip how to do it, please.

I mean I wanted to define channel id as an argument but how I can save it for server so it won't save it for all servers.

Comment: You'd have to set up a database for that so you can save configurations such as the one you want.

Comment: Well, I'll try to set up database but what next? how I can save data on it? And how i can read it from it? As I said I'm really new developer and I never used databases and other things like this.

Comment: And also can I make database on my pc? So it'll be faster to read data from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to set up a database and store the channel and server IDs there. If you're just starting out, try using [LowDB](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb), which isn't exactly what I'd call a "database", but should get the job done for now.

If you want to use an actual database that is still very easy to understand, give [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) a try.

To get your feature working, you'd need to store the server and channel IDs to the database, and check it whenever a new user joins.

Comment: Thanks you, I'll set it up but what, after I mean how i can save data of id channel to use it, I found something about value and write, so should i just make my bot write id that user give in "post" that's server as an value and after that read it from it in welcome command? And how to do it?